# Firemonkey & Android 64-bit requirement

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

> Starting August 1, 2019:
>
> All new apps and app updates that include native code are required to
>   provide 64-bit versions in addition to 32-bit versions when publishing
>   to Google Play.

How in a Firemonkey application, can I set app to meet 64-bit requirements?

I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3.

Comment: You simply cannot do that. Android 64-bit support is scheduled for 10.4 later this year. If you need early access apply for the beta.

Comment: You can read the [Feature Matrix](https://www.embarcadero.com/features/feature-matrix) to see what is (and is not) available in the current version. If it's not mentioned in the matrix, it's not yet available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's impossible to compile a 64bit Android app with RAD Studio 10.3.

Android 64bit support is only available in RAD Studio 10.3.3 and later as can be seen from the [August 2019 Roadmap](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/august-2019-delphi-android-beta-plans-august-roadmap-update). So you'll need to get RAD Studio 10.3.3 if you want to compile an Android 64bit application.

Comment: Or join the beta program and get a beta ahead of time

Comment: @Pointer As far as I'm aware. From 1 Aug 2019, all apps submitted to Google Play Store needs to have a 64bit version. You can't submit or update any app without having a 64bit version.

Comment: @OmarReis The biggest change between apps compiled with Tokyo (targeting API 14) and Rio (Targeting API 28), is the need to code for explicit permission requests. There are questions here on SO that answer that.

Answer (score 3):

This is an official blog post from Embarcadero about Delphi 64bit. You can request an extension to the 64-bit requirement, as follow:

**Official Post From Sarina DuPont:**

As you’re probably aware, starting August 1st, 2019, applications in the Google Play Store must support 64-bit. We are working to provide 64-bit Android support in RAD Studio, but in the meantime, Google’s Play Store team is considering extensions to the 64-bit requirement for our Delphi and C++Builder customers on an app-by-app basis (see steps below).

To ensure your C++Builder or Delphi Android 32-bit application is accepted into the Play Store, you will need to submit a request for an extension after following the regular Google Play Store publishing steps in the Console.

Note: Starting August 1st, 2019, only app updates to existing Android 32-bit applications will be considered for an extension by the Google Play Store team, not new 32-bit Android applications. For new Android 32-bit applications, it’s recommended that you submit them as soon as possible and start asking for an extension now, so that you are not impacted by the deadline come August 1st.

How to request an extension:

1) Visit https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing

2) Fill out the form and select ‘I submitted a new app or app update but it is not live’

3) In the feedback field, indicate that your application was built with Embarcadero Delphi or C++Builder, and that you’d like to request an extension to the 64-bit requirement

Embarcadero customers can submit extension requests for Android 32-bit app updates to existing Google Play Store applications until August 2020.

Comment: I would also add some verbiage on when you think you can produce a 64-bit version. I followed the above and one of the questions I got back was, "I'm being instructed to ask if you can provide a more concrete estimation for when you will be able to provide a 64 bit version.  We understand that you can't provide an exact date (since Embarcadero's own compliance date is sort of an X factor at this time), but would you say you could have 64 bit versions of your apps available within (for example) 7 days of Embarcadero finishing its update?".

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment unless you update to Rad Studio 10.3.3.

However, here are some alternative (aggressive) solutions :

- If you have a limited user base (Corporation/B2B), you can instruct users to sideload your application outside of the store.
- Publish on an alternative Android App store, there are many, with less restrictions!
- You can publish 32-bit on Google play, but for Android pre-9 version.

Answer (score -1):

This also depends on if the you are using C++ or Delphi, it looks like C++ support for android 64 bit won't be available for at least a year.

Comment: The question is tagged Delphi.